# How can I change tooltip in a chart in my ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm using Angular and I have this chart in the .ts of my component:

```
tabDateBallons = Object.keys(this.ballonMap);
tabValueBallons = Object.values(this.ballonMap);
let t:number[] = [];
tabValueBallons.forEach(x=>t.push(x.length));

new Chart("myChart", {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: tabDateBallons,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: t,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I change the tooltip when I move the cursor over the values?

Comment: What do you want to do with the tooltip, documentation can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Comment: I want to display all the informations of my ballons for a date when I put the mouse on the differents values of the chart